# How to programmatically set the margin between icon and title of menu item of Navigation Drawer in Android?

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am developing an Android App. In my app, I am using navigation drawer and navigation view. But I set the menu item for them programmatically. For a menu item, I set both icon and title. But I am having a problem with that. That is I cannot set the spacing between icon and title that I programmatically added to menu.

This is how I programmatically add item to menu

```
Menu menu = leftDrawer.getMenu();
        SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID, 99, 99, "Others");

        subMenu.add(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID,96,96,"Monthly Leaderboard").setIcon(R.drawable.leaderboard_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LeaderboardActivity.class));
                return false;
            }
        });

        subMenu.add(MAIN_MENU_ITEM_GROUP_ID,96,96,"Settings").setIcon(R.drawable.settings_icon).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But spacing between between icon and title is not properly set.

This is the screenshot of my problem

[image]

As you can see in screenshot, spacing between left side of screen and icon and spacing between icon and title are not same. How can I set the spacing between icon and title of menu item programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not supposed to be the same. From the [Navigation Drawer guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), you'll note this screenshot:

[image: Navigation Drawer specs]

The side margin is `16dp` (and `24dp` on tablets) while the titles are aligned with the `72dp` keyline.

Since the `NavigationView` seeks to exactly match the material design guidelines, there is no way to change the spacing.

Comment: Thanks you so much. U get rid of my doubt. Now I am clear.